# Find $f\left(x\right)$, given that $f''\left(x\right)=3x^2+1$, $f\left(0\right)=1$ and $f\left(2\right)=-1$ and that it is a 2ndorder derivable funct.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\left(x\right)$ is a 2ndorder derivable function. Given that $f''\left(x\right)=3x^2+1$, $f\left(0\right)=1$ and $f\left(2\right)=-1$, find $f\left(x\right)$.

Using
$f\left(x\right)\:=\:x^2\:+\:c$
as the general equation for a second-order derivable function I've arrived at this:

$f\left(0\right)\:=\:1$

$1\:=\:\left(0\right)^2\:+\:c$

$1\:=\:c$

and

$f\left(2\right)\:=\:-1$

$-1\:=\:\left(2\right)^2\:+\:c$

$-1\:=\:4\:+\:c$

$-5\:=\:c$

So $f\left(x\right)\:$ ends up like this:

$f\left(x\right)\:=\:x^2\:-\:5$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. You could have figured out noticing that $c=1=-5$ that is false.
To solve this you need to find the antiderivative of the function using integrals.
$f(x)=\int f'(x)dx$ and $f'(x)=\int f''(x)dx$, so:
$f'(x)=\int f''(x)dx=\int(3x^{2}+1)dx=x^{3}+x+c$
$f(x)=\int f'(x)dx=\int(x^{3}+x+c)dx= \frac{1}{4}x^{4}+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+cx+d$
To find the value of the constants $c$ and $d$ use $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=-1$.
$f(0)=d=1$
$f(2)= \frac{1}{4}2^{4}+\frac{1}{2}2^{2}+2c+d=4+2+2c+1=-1 \Rightarrow c=-4$
Therefore
$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^{4}+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}-4x+1$
I used basic rules of integration. In general to solve find a fuction given the derivative you use integrals.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \iint 3x^2 + 1 \, \mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4}x^4 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 +c_1x+c_2$$

$$f(0) = c_2 = 1$$
$$f(2) = 2c_1 + 1 + 6 = -1 \implies c_1 = -4$$

Hence,

$$f(x) = \boxed{\frac{1}{4}x^4 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - 4x + 1}$$